# Why is the water solubility of CO worse than that of CO2?

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, computational-chemistry, solubility

I tried my best to ask SciFinder, Google, and Google Scholar the wrong questions ...

I found many paper on the fitting of the solubility to some equations to be able to calculate the amount of $\ce{CO}$ in water, but I could hardly find any explanation on the low solubility. Only one paper [1] dealt with it.

Why is $\ce{CO}$ way less soluble in water than $\ce{CO2}$, despite, *e.g.*, the first having a dipole moment and the latter doesn't? What am I missing?

---

[1] H. Sato, N. Matubayasi, M. Nakahara, F. Hirata, "Which carbon oxide is more soluble? *Ab initio* study on carbon monoxide and dioxide in aqueous solution," *Chemical Physics Letters* **2000**, *323(3-4)*, 257–262 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0009-2614(00)00508-X).

Comment: Is this gonna be both Q&A?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35603/why-is-co-practically-nonpolar https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35603/why-is-co-practically-nonpolar

Comment: Well, CO2 is a great deal more polar.

Comment: Because if it's serious then your comparing it with wrong compound - comparison between CO and **N2** would be interesting, but CO2 reacts with water, which changes everything. BTW @IvanNeretin don't even start that again...

Comment: @Mithoron I will if I have to.

Comment: I was going to comment on the polarity discussion here, but there's clearly some cross-talk I'm missing... :/

Comment: Polar does not mean anything. It is among the most ambiguous words used in chemistry.

Comment: @M.Farooq IMHO, "stable" is much worse. It is not used here, though.

Comment: @M.Farooq Do not confuse lack of meaning with multiple meanings :-) It's also a relative location on planet earth or an adjective, or the name of various commercial brands.

Comment: Please note that OP is correct as referring to the dipole moments and not to a more ambiguous (for some) polarity. The linked article find its justification in dealing with ab initio methods rather than common sense. When we speak about CO2 solubility I do not think we intend "free" CO2. Perhaps the article does but it is not what common intuition means. That is the answer is probably that by @Oscar Lanzi integrated by Mithoron comment.

Comment: @Alchimista, I was referring to comments. OP is using correct wordings.

Comment: @Mithoron unfortunately it is not Q&A

Comment: But it could be - discuss reaction with water and relevant equilibria, and it would be done.

Comment: Most CO2 dissolved in water [is actually CO2, not reacted to form carbonic acid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid). So a reaction-based explanation misses.  For an alternative hypothesis see the answers.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $\ce{CO2}$ does not have a dipole moment does not really mean it's nonpolar.  What $\ce{CO2}$ has is a **quadrupole**, two opposing dipoles that occupy different portions of space (opposite sides of the carbon atom).

Ordinarily we expect an electrostatic interaction with a quadrupole to be relatively weak, but in $\ce{CO2}$ the component dipoles are strong and at close range the water molecules can "home in" on one end of the molecule and interact selectively with the corresponding component dipole.  Thereby the electrostatic interaction between water and the $\ce{CO2}$ quadrupole is stronger than the interaction between water and the weak $\ce{CO}$ dipole.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54115/quadrupole-moment-of-a-molecule

Comment: Yes carbon dioxide has a weak microwave rotational spectrum as well.