# Estimation of dipole moments in aromatic compounds

Tags: aromatic-compounds, resonance, dipole, inductive-effect

If it asks to compare dipole moment in aromatic compounds then do we see inductive or resonance effects or do we see a mix of both?

E.g. we have to compare dipole moment in pyrrole and furan then in one we have opp direction of dipole moment in both why? Like it's a specific question but I wish to understand the mechanism behind every such tricky question so that I can do on my own.

Or suppose we have ortho hydroxyphenol then what would I say the direction of dipole moment would be? Would it be inwards towards benzene or outwards towards $-\ce{OH}$ group. It's not because of convention doubt, but like whether it's the resonance effect that dominates which would result in majorly + on $-\ce{OH}$ group and - on $-\ce{Ph}$ group or is it the inductive effect dominating which would result in opposite sign.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the origin of the "positive-to-negative" convention concerning dipole moments in chemistry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44605/what-is-the-origin-of-the-positive-to-negative-convention-concerning-dipole-mo)

Comment: Then your question is too broad.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96923/how-to-compare-dipole-moment-in-thiophene-furan-and-pyrrole

Comment: No I think I have got what the OP wants to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read up in my text book that dipole moment direction of phenol is towards OH group so I guess O being highly electronegative pulls the electrons more and participates less in resonance hence it has deta negative charge on it thus acc to convention dipole moment direction is from positive to negative hence direction is towards OH group.